# How to fit fullsreen canvas and keep elements position?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to make an interactive map for the website. There are areas under the house, and I want to mark them with different colors. I add canvas, path, and canvasBackground.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 756 349 L 744 308 L 787 310 L 794 346 z');

path.set({
  fill: 'red',
  opacity: 0.5
});
canvas.add(path);

canvas.setBackgroundImage('phase3.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  width: canvas.width,
  height: canvas.height,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top'
});
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
```

Then i need to fit to screen. I try to use canvas.setDimensions(), but its not work.

[Demo](http://alexeykremnev.ru/fabric.html)

Thx for help. Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

How about put

```
canvas.setDimensions({
  width: body_w,
  height: body_h
});
```

to just behind `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var width = 1600;
    var height = 900;
    var scaleFactor = 1;

     if(screen.width < 1281) {
        scaleFactor = 0.8;
      } else if (screen.width < 1361) {
        scaleFactor = 0.85;
      } else if (screen.width < 1441) {
        scaleFactor = 0.9;
      } else if (screen.width < 1601) {
        scaleFactor = 1;
      }  else {
        scaleFactor = 1.2;
      }
      width = width * scaleFactor;
      height = height * scaleFactor;

      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
      canvas.setWidth(width);
      canvas.setHeight(height);
      canvas.calcOffset();

    if(scaleFactor != 1) {
      for(var i=0; i<canvas._objects.length; i++){
         canvas._objects[i].scale(scaleFactor);
         canvas._objects[i].setLeft(canvas._objects[i].left * scaleFactor);
         canvas._objects[i].setTop(canvas._objects[i].top * scaleFactor);
         canvas._objects[i].setCoords();
      }
      canvas.renderAll();
    } else {canvas.renderAll();}
```

I found this tip on stackoverflow, but lost link )